# How to update data onClick on an item from listView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView populated from another activity where I have some edittexts in which users enter values, and this values are showed in the listView. The problem is that I want after showing values in the listView, to have the possibility to click on an item an change the values of it. It's doing this, but when you click an item, it opens the activity where you should put those values, but with the editTexts empty, and I would like to have them filled with the values showed in the listView. Thanks a lot !

Here is the code for updating data, but I couldn't make those int arg working.

```
//click to update data
        userLista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adauga_absente.class);
                i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", d.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", stime.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", etime.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", freq.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", mode.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", station.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", loc.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", tqsl.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", mqsl.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", comm.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Comment: You have few  `EditText` in `Adauga_absente.java` where you need the values of clicked item in listview if i understand your question right?

Comment: Yes. Adauga_absente is the activity where you add values, then this values are showed in Absente, the activity where the listView is. This code is from Absente, and I want to have on this click, when the activity starts, the editTexts from Adauga_absente filled with values entered before.Thanks !

Comment: What is `user_fName` and what is the problem. You are on the right track in using intent to pass values between activities.

Comment: also **but I couldn't make those int arg working** what int arg are you talking about?

Comment: The name of the string -> `private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I'm talking about this `int arg2,long arg3` , `.get(arg2))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59994/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ezekiel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Adauga_absente` Class you should use :

```
String Fname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Fname");
String Lname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Lname");
...
```

And then pre-fill your EditText with those Strings